# How to rewrite the words function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How do I rewrite the words function in Haskell, i.e not using the case where format, but using some other format? So far I've tried:

```
import Data.Char 
mywords s
       | dropWhile isSpace s == "" = []
       | dropWhile isSpace s == s' = w : mywords s'' 
            where (w, s'') = break isSpace s'
```

and

```
import Data.Char 
mywords s = if dropWhile isSpace s == "" then [] else w : mywords s'
            where (w, s') = break isSpace s
```

But they don't work. Why don't they work? How do you rewrite the words function in a different way that is easier to understand?

Original prelude code:

```
import Data.Char
mywords s                 =  case dropWhile isSpace s of
                                "" -> []
                                s' -> w : mywords s''
                                      where (w, s'') =
                                             break isSpace s'
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the versions you tried? Knowing the problem is the first step to finding a solution.

Comment: A style point: you should generally avoid `xs == ""` or `xs == []`.  These checks force the list elements to be comparable for equality (*i.e.*, have instances of `Eq`), which is unnecessary.  Use `null xs` instead, which returns `True` if and only if `xs` is empty; better yet is often to use pattern-matching, but of course this question is about getting rid of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with the first one is the line

```
| dropWhile isSpace s == s'
```

You haven't actually defined s' at this point. Instead I think you'd want something closer to

```
myWords :: String -> [String]
myWords s | s' == ""  = ""
          | otherwise = word : myWords rest
  where s' = dropWhile isSpace s
        (word, rest) = break isSpace s'
```

Now we define `s'` and check if it's an empty string, otherwise we stick the first word on and keep going.

For the second one, you've forgotten to strip of leading whitespace. In so when you pass it `"  foo"` it breaks it into the words `("", "  foo")` and loops forever. Instead you just want the same idea as the first solution

```
myWords' s = if s' == "" then [] else word : myWords' rest
  where s' = dropWhile isSpace s
        (word, rest) = break isSpace s'
```

Notice that these are essentially the same since we're just using the guards like a fancy if expression.

If you want shorter code, I suppose you could do something like

```
myWords' s = if dropWhile isSpace s == "" then [] else uncurry (:).fmap myWords'.break isSpace.dropWhile isSpace $ s
```

It's just a bit pointless and illegible. 3 lines of code is pretty darn short.

Comment: Why do you have to define s' in this version whereas in the original version it's not defined?

Comment: @user2108462 You can't just randomly introduce variables in Haskell, you have to define them. In this case you just started using `s'` but never defined it which is illegal in Haskell

Comment: Yes it was, a case expression can be used to bind names, but you're just using `==` which is really just a normal function. It's like calling `f unboundName` and expecting it to figure out the value.

Comment: Is there any other way to implicitly bind the name other than using the case keyword?

Comment: @user2108462 Yes, you can use the `where` clause or in the original toplevel function definition if it's just an argument, or with `let`

Comment: So it's impossible to write any code that's shorter than yours if we're using the guards or if-then format?

Comment: In this case, the right approach is either a `case` expression or a `where` clause is the right approach

Comment: It's impossible to write it using the guards or if-then format without using the where clause to define s'?

Comment: @user2108462 Sure, you could just inline every occurence of `s'` to `dropWhile isSpace s`. But why would you wan tot?

Comment: So I can write this? import Data.Char 
mywords s
       | dropWhile isSpace s == "" = []
       | otherwise = w : mywords s'' 
   where (w, s'') = break isSpace (dropWhile isSpace s)

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop, we construct a list of words equipped with a `Bool` tag. If the tag is `True`, the topmost word is "under construction" and we can prepend characters to it. If the tag is `False`, the topmost word is "done", so any new non-whitespace character must be considered the last character of a new topmost word.

```
import Data.Char

words = fst . loop
  where
    loop "" = ([], False)
    loop (c:cs)
      | isSpace c = (words cs, False)
      | otherwise =
        case loop cs of
          (ws, False) -> ([c]:ws, True)    -- c is the last character of a new word
          (w:ws, True) -> ((c:w):ws, True) -- c can be prepended to the current word
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile.